# CSS анимация после перетаскивания

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хочу сделать анимацию после перетаскивания. С перетаскиванием проблем нет, просто предположим есть `event` `document.omouseup`, чтобы убрать лишний js.

Анимация простая: `background` стал синим, через секунду вернулся обратно (отсутствие `background`).

Я вот только не понимаю как это сделать. Ведь просто вставить такое не подойдет:

```
.color {
    transition-property: background-color;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

UPD: Вот только что придумал как сделать можно, ниже код. Это самый правильный вариант?

```
document.omouseup = () => {
  // делаем анимацию
  myElem.style.background = 'blue';
  myElem.classList.add('color');
  myElem.style.background = '';
  // убираем последствия анимации
  setTimeout(() => {
     myElem.classList.remove('color');
  },1000);
}
```

Comment: С перетаскиванием, в смысле drag'n'drop? А если юзер потащит и сразу отпустит? В вашем случае анимация сработает, хоть это и не нужно... В jQuery можно создать своё событие, вот статья, гуглите.
http://xandeadx.ru/blog/javascript/355